# Updating relationship issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, foreign-keys

I'm having an issue updating all records of a relationship modal. Instead only one model is updating all records. I need EACH record to be updated.

I have a MODEL which has holds a "retailer" and this model has an `hasMany` relationship with a "Location" model. The location model **belongsTo** the retailer model.

The Location model holds Addresses for retailers. Some Retailers have many locations (addresses). I have tried many solutions but cannot seems to get any to work. The only solution that has worked is using `first();` which updates the first record, but I need to update all address records. I'm really tearing my hair out and i've been stuck going on 4 days. I'm literally ready to commit suicide. Any help. Please.

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {
     $location = $request->only(
         'street_number', 
         'street_address',
         'city',
         'state',
         'postcode',
         'country',
         'longitude',
         'latitude',
         'country_code'
     ); 

     $insert = Location::where('id', $id);
     $insert->update($location);

     return Redirect::route('retailers.edit', $id)
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validation)
        ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.')
     ;
  }
```

Comment: You need to update 'all' address (locations) records?

Answer (score 0):

In order to update all related location records you should use the **update()** method on your relation like in the following:

```
$updatedLocationData = [
  'country_code' => 123
];

$retailer->locations()->update($updatedLocationData);
```